# why the PIV of full wave rectifier is 2vm

Tags: diodes, rectifier

Peak inverse voltage (PIV) is the maximum voltage a diode can handle in reverse bias condition.

Why does the PIV of the diodes in a full wave rectifier need to be 2×V<sub>m</sub>?
(where V<sub>m</sub> is the peak voltage of the input AC signal.)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: And what is a "Vm"? perhaps a "mV"?

Comment: Vm is the amplitude of the input signal

Comment: what is the need of calculating PIV and how can we say that piv is 2Vm

Answer (score 4):

Consider the circuit diagram of a center-tapped full wave rectifier where D1 is forward biased and D2 is reverse biased.[image]

The maximum reverse voltage appearing across will be 2*Vp. Where Vp is the amplitude of input signal.

So the diode that is used in a center-tapped full wave rectifier should have a PIV of atleast twice the peak voltage of input sine wave. Otherwise diode breakdown will happen and current will flow through the reverse biased diode. And the circuit is not a rectifier anymore.

Similarly, PIV for a full wave bridge rectifier will be Vp.

Answer (score 3):

The minimum required PIV is 2 * Vp where Vp is the peak input voltage if there is a capacitor output filter, because the capacitor holds Vp (minus diode drop) whilst the input voltage goes to -Vp on the negative input cycles. The voltage the diode must stand off is thus 2*Vp.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6tNcI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If the load was a resistor rather than a capacitor, only Vp PIV rating would be required.

Comment: Your and Nidhin's answers have complementary points. Full wave can be achieved by several means and his example does not need a capacitor to deliver 2Vp to a diode.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon As the question refers specifically to a FW rectifier, Nidhin's answer is more applicable to the actual question, +1 for him.